# How to highlight form field if invalid in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am having a registration form. I need to validate each field value and hightlight the particular field if it is invalid and move page to respective field area.

I am using a span to validate the field value.

But I want to validate th form when ng-clicked on submit button and highlight the field if the mandatory field value is empty.

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group fields col-sm-2 col-xs-4" ng-class="{'has-error': (tForm.fname.$dirty || tForm.$submitted) && tForm.fname.$invalid }"><label for ="fname">FIRST NAME *</label><br>
            <input  type="text" name="fname" class="form-control1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4" autocomplete="off" ng-required="true" ng-model="model.firstName" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/" ng-minlength ="1"/>

            <span ng-show="!tForm.fname.$error.required && tForm.fname.$error.minlength && tForm.fname.$dirty && !tForm.fname.$error.minlength" class="help-block">
                Fistname must be atleast 1 character.
            </span>
            <span ng-show="!tForm.fname.$error.required && !tForm.fname.$error.minlength && tForm.fname.$error.pattern && tForm.fname.$dirty" class="help-block">
                Must contain only Characters
            </span>
            <span ng-show="tForm.fname.$dirty && tForm.fname.$error.required" class="help-block" >
                First name is required
            </span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below plunker for validation

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0OXhlI?utm_source=angular-js.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation&p=preview)

```
Use Bootstrap showerrors directive
```